# How do I describe a method that has no side effects if an exception is thrown during execution?

Tags: terminology, exception-safe

I just can't remember the terminology used for this and other related properties.

EDIT - Maybe such a concept doesn't exist but I remember reading something in Effective C++ (or More Effective C++) where he advocated using swaps to commit changes last in the function because the vector swap functions were guaranteed not to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to say that the function is "exception-safe". See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety.

The Wikipedia article further divides the safety into various levels. This is the one that is relevant here:

> 2. Commit or rollback semantics, also known as strong exception safety or no-change guarantee: Operations can fail, but failed operations are guaranteed to have no side effects so all data retain original values.

There's a reference to an STL design document that introduces exception safety and commit-or-rollback semantics: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1997/N1077.asc

Comment: Yes, thanks. It was these different levels of exception safety I was looking for. Maybe you could add them to your answer?

Comment: I didn't want to copy all of it, so I just quoted the one that is the most relevant here. Does that look ok?

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of an [exception guarantee](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html), in particular the "strong guarantee".

Answer (score 1):

Having read your edit, I suspect your title is slightly incorrect. Do you really mean it has no side effects *whether or not an exception is thrown* (as per the current wording) or that it has no side effects when an exception is thrown, but if the method completes without throwing an exception then it will/can have side effects? There's a pretty big difference :)

The latter is described in Accelerated C# 2008 as "exception neutrality".